# How do I keep the rear LCD on longer on a Nikon D200?

Tags: nikon, camera-controls, rear-lcd

The LCD on the back of my Nikon D200 has a fairly short screensaver timeout that turns it off if I am not doing anything. This is fine, but sometimes I want to look at something carefully for a while. How can I lock the display on temporarily so that it does not go dark?

Answer (score 1):

The D200 has menu C5 where the Monitor Off delay can be adjusted from 10 seconds to 10 minutes.  This LCD duration will affect your battery life, but lightly tapping the shutter release button will turn it off.

Conversely, with a short delay, retapping the preview button will turn it back on.